# How risky is it to allow global SSH access to EC2 host?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

SSH documentation suggests restricting SSH access to your personal IP address. But how likely is it that an intruder could obtain your 2048 bit SSH key in order to gain access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not very risky, but limiting access is a best practice.

At minimum it will attract the attention of bots that will continually slam your server with brute force attempts, and expose ypur DoS surface.   It also puts you in the  "more likely to be hackable" basket.

It is somewhat unlikely that you will be hacked as a result of a weakness in SSH  (but that is not unprecedented) but it does remove a layer of security, and if other things are misconfigured, its one more place things can go wrong.

Think of good security as being made up of layers. Allowing SSH from anywhere strips back a layer. Use a VPN  to add another layer instead.